# Fixed-top Nav Is too low

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navigation, offset

On my site http://richardclifford.net/, whenever a user clicks the one-page `#id` elements it goes to the very first piece of content the  and ignored all the container padding and h2 margin-top to look like this

[image: BEFORE]

I'd want it to scroll to include the padding or have an offset like this.

[image]

I've add an offset on my scrollspy but that is not fixing it and not sure how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use margin-top and padding-top for this with out affecting to the front side of the website. Try to add **-50px to margin top and 50px to padding top**. This will fix your issue.

[image: See the attachment]

Comment: I tried this with 
div#work {
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
and it still goes right on the header when click the #id in the nav.

Comment: Try to add it inline <div style”margin-top:-50px; padding-top:50px;” .... >

Comment: Still not working for me.   I currently have it like like for my work section with no luck https://screencast.com/t/v8kNqjvvv8

Comment: I can see the equal sign is missing on your code. style=“” hope it will work. Good luck!

Comment: ahhh can't believe i missed that.   Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

add `margin-top: -50px;padding-top: 50px;` to target id it works

```
#work,#about,#contact,#copyright{
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: this seems to have fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One common way is to add invisible pseudo elements to the original target elements of the links via CSS, like this:

```
#work::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -60px; 
  height: 60px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will "extend" the element with that ID in a way which causes the anchor to be 60px above the main element (can be any value), without causing any other visible changes.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesnt seem to work for me.